# 'list' object has no attribute 'prefixed_order_by_field' Django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

In order to show plural tables in a view using Django-tables2, I assigned plural tables to a table variable and use RequestConfig as follows,

views.py

```
tables = [ScheduleTable(qs_t2), ScheduleTable(qs_t2125), ScheduleTable(qs_gst)]
RequestConfig(request).configure(tables)
export_format = request.GET.get('_export', None)
if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
    exporter = TableExport(export_format, tables)
    return exporter.response('tables.{}'.format(export_format))
return render(request, 'report/companies.html', {'table':tables})
```

"'list' object has no attribute 'prefixed_order_by_field" was the error message when 'RequestConfig' was executing. Do you know why?

Comment: Clearly, the configure method is not expecting a list.

Comment: Then is there another way to show multi-tables in a view?

Comment: Please refer to my updated code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the efficient way, but I got a result anyway. I just followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619369/django-tables2-display-multiple-tables) from another question.

views.py

```
t2Table = ScheduleTable(qs_t2)
t2125Table = ScheduleTable(qs_t2125) 
gstTable = ScheduleTable(qs_gst)
tables = {
    't2Table': t2Table, 
    't2125Table': t2125Table, 
    'gstTable': gstTable,
    }
RequestConfig(request).configure(ScheduleTable(qs_t2))
RequestConfig(request).configure(ScheduleTable(qs_t2125))
RequestConfig(request).configure(ScheduleTable(qs_gst))

return render(request, 'report/monthly_schedule.html', tables)
```

html

```
<p><h4>T2</h4>{% render_table t2Table %}</p>
<p><h4>T2125</h4>{% render_table t2125Table %}</p>
<p><h4>GST</h4>{% render_table gstTable %}</p>
```

Comment: There is http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#multitablemixin, which automates this, but requires you to use Class based views.